# Cakephp session is not setting from another machine

Tags: php, cakephp

I am using cakephp2.0. The session is not setting if I access my cakephp application from another machine. In core.php, session security is 'low' and given 'cake' for storing the session. I have tried with different values. Its not even creating the CAKEPHP cookie in the browser. Everything is working fine if I run the application from the local computer. I have tried with simple php script and the session is setting from another machine.. The problem is only with cake. please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried tweaking some the Session settings in core.php?

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
            'defaults' => 'php',
    'cookie'=>'CAKEPHP',
    'cookieTimeout'=>1000,
    'checkAgent'=>false
        ));
```

Setting checkAgent to false opens you up to session hijacking so be careful